# Flutter Navigator pop / remove all except the latest

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

In my flutter apps, there is a **main page**, when user is back to that page (regardless from where) they are not suppose to tap (or swipe) back to the previous page.

Currently we are using `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil`.

But there is a problem, on and off, we will have programmers forgot to remove all the routes before navigating back to the main page.

Is there a way for us to pop / clear or remove all the navigator's route at the **main page** itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use willPopScope and return false always like the following

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child:  Scaffold(
         appBar:  AppBar(
          title: Text("Home Page"),
         ),
         body:  Center(
          child:  Text("Home Page"),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, there are some errors.
1. ``new`` is no longer needed,
2. ``onWillPop: () async => false``.
But it solved my problem

Comment: Oh yeah you are correct. Onwillpop needs a function. I added false directly. Sorry my bad. Will edit now